# Umbraco 7 xpath expression filter - i cant get it to load any nodes at all

Tags: xpath, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to xpath. I am trying to use the "nuPickers XML Dropdown picker" on Umbraco 7.3.4

but no matter what xpath xpression filter i use, the dropdown remains empty no nodes is being loaded in to the dropdown

i tried the following filters:

$root/

$site/

/*/

$ancestor-or-self::Home/

but to no avail, none of them loads any nodes

i actually want to select all the "Club" nodes under "Clubcontainer", but i cant get it to load any nodes, nevermind the specific ones that i actually want. My Umbraco.config looks as follows: (some nodes removed under to only show relevant nodes for my filter query.)

```
<root id="-1">
  <Home id="2081" key="ebb9222f-f26c-4462-9f5d-43dba520326f" parentID="-1" level="1" creatorID="0" sortOrder="0" createDate="2015-12-29T12:19:53" updateDate="2016-01-09T17:27:57" nodeName="Home" urlName="home" path="-1,2081" isDoc="" nodeType="1070" creatorName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerID="0" template="1049" nodeTypeAlias="Home">
    <Clubcontainer id="2094" key="6f11e986-3e29-4555-8bc4-5a847600704c" parentID="2081" level="2" creatorID="0" sortOrder="3" createDate="2015-12-29T13:20:15" updateDate="2016-01-09T17:27:57" nodeName="Chess Clubs" urlName="chess-clubs" path="-1,2081,2094" isDoc="" nodeType="2092" creatorName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerID="0" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="Clubcontainer">
      <Club id="2103" key="856c9937-cf4c-481b-aaba-487e0dcee199" parentID="2094" level="3" creatorID="0" sortOrder="0" createDate="2016-01-07T22:41:28" updateDate="2016-01-09T17:27:57" nodeName="Hlalefang Alexandra Chess club" urlName="hlalefang-alexandra-chess-club" path="-1,2081,2094,2103" isDoc="" nodeType="2093" creatorName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerID="0" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="Club">
        <president><![CDATA[Mr President]]></president>
        <presidentCell><![CDATA[0123 13131313]]></presidentCell>
        <presidentEmail><![CDATA[johnDoe@example.net]]></presidentEmail>
      </Club>
      <Club id="2104" key="a5d73286-9572-445b-9d3a-7f758de64d0e" parentID="2094" level="3" creatorID="0" sortOrder="1" createDate="2016-01-07T22:42:27" updateDate="2016-01-09T17:27:57" nodeName="Chess Excellence" urlName="chess-excellence" path="-1,2081,2094,2104" isDoc="" nodeType="2093" creatorName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerName="Gerrie Pretorius" writerID="0" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="Club">
        <president><![CDATA[Jane Doe]]></president>
        <presidentCell><![CDATA[012 345 6789]]></presidentCell>
        <webAddress><![CDATA[http://www.example.net]]></webAddress>
        <presidentEmail><![CDATA[janedoe@example.net]]></presidentEmail>
      </Club>
    </Clubcontainer>
  </Home>
</root>
```

If some-one can help me witht his i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried `/root/Home/Clubcontainer/Club`?

Comment: @KeithHall yes, i tried that aswell. 
Is it possible that something else is wrong and this is not because the Xpath statement is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer provided to me by Marc Goodson [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7//74144-xpath-expression-filter-why-cant-i-see-any-nodes-id10t-error)

To load all Nodes of documentType Club use //Club

or to load the specific club nodes:

$ancestorOrSelf/ancestor-or-self::Home[position()=1]//Clubcontainer//Club